# Flutter Web and Django routing directly from URL

Tags: django, flutter

I have Flutter web and Django backend (REST API). I want to serve flutter web from Django directly. Every thing works fine if I start from domain (localhost:8000) and navigate to (localhost:8000/others) from web. But it shows  404 if I push URL (localhost:8000/others) direct from browser.

Note: On flutter only it works properly (used Navigator 2.0). But on integrating with Django its not working.

this is the error I get.

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/47693882/122642537-a448d400-d12a-11eb-9dcb-592e1371066f.mp4

[My Urls.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztaZJ.png)

Comment: But my error is not that. please check the video I posted.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem because of this, django server and flutter index.html both  run on local with port 8000

you try upload index.html on a host

and also deploy django on another server

with this your problem maybe solved